# Import file name into DE as field value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, import

Do you know if it is possible to 'read' a file name from a triggered automation/import activity and then use the string in the filename to populate a field in a DE in which the records from that file have been imported into?

ie, file name is segmentid_123, and when I import those records I want all the rows imported to have segmentid field as 123

I'm assuming this is somewhat possible as import activities can fetch a '%%filename from trigger%%' string from the automation.

Even just having the entire file name imported into the DE for all the rows imported from the file would be a start for us to transform it in sql.

Comment: This is not possible from an end user standpoint. You could talk to your Account Rep about a custom solution, but I have been told that this is something that can impose a huge security risk and is not available outside SFMC internal uses.